# Spring MVC, Servlet 3.0: how to create resource-ref

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlet-3.0

I am developing a web application with Spring MVC (4.2.3) and
Servlet 3.0 API, so there is no web.xml.

My WebConfig.java is as follows:

```
...
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {...})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;

}
```

I am creating this spring application by copying from a java application with
Servlet < 3.0, so there is a web.xml which contains this section regarding
the data source:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/DefaultDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
</resource-ref>
```

How do I create such a setting in my Spring MVC application where there is no
web.xml?

In the meantime I have had a look at the "Java Servlet Specification Version 3.0".
It says about @Resource:

> The @Resource annotation is used to declare a reference to a resource
>   such as a data source... This annotation is equivalent to declaring a
>   resource-ref...
>
> @Resource example:

```
@Resource private javax.sql.DataSource catalogDS;
public getProductsByCategory() {
 // get a connection and execute the query
 Connection conn = catalogDS.getConnection();
..
}
```

> In the example code above, a servlet, filter, or listener declares a
>   field catalogDS of type javax.sql.DataSource for which the reference
>   to the data source is injected by the container prior to the component
>   being made available to the application.
>   The data source JNDI mapping is inferred from the field name
>   “catalogDS” and type (javax.sql.DataSource). Moreover, the catalogDS
>   resource no longer needs to be defined in the deployment descriptor.

Unfortunately I don't know how to use it and how to get it connected to Springs JDBCTemplate. Is

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

the right location at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a listener by extending

```
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

and added the annotation

```
@WebListener.
```

In that listener the field

```
@Resource private javax.sql.DataSource catalogDS;
```

is successfully populated.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html

Comment: Thank you! However as to my knowledge javax.servlet.ServletContextListener is a servlet container managed component and I need the javax.sql.DataSource in the Spring application context.